# Difference between Spring Data JPA and ORM

Tags: orm, spring-data-jpa

Following are my questions about `Spring Data JPA`.

**Q1** Is Spring Data JPA an ORM? If not, then what is it?

**Q2** What is the advantage of spring data JPA?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Q1 Is Spring Data JPA, ORM? If not then, what it is?

No. It is a system to create "automatic" Data Access Objects (DAOs) for you at compile time, and *uses* an ORM (like Hibernate) in these DAOs.

> Q2 What is the advantage of Spring Data?

1. You don't need to write your own DAOs
2. You can easily swap JPA implementations
3. You can even switch to non-JPA data sources like MongoDB

An example, you create an entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  ...
}
```

and a repository definition like this:

```
public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, Long> {
  //that's it, nothing else. no code
}
```

Spring Data JPA will then create a proxy repository class (proxying method calls to SimpleJpaRepository) that you can use to select, insert, update, and delete your Foo objects.

```
@Controller
public class FooController {
  
  @Autowired
  private FooRepository fooRepository;

  @RequestMapping("/")
  @ResponseBody
  Foo getFoo() {
    return fooRepository.findOne(1L); //look, you didn't need to write a DAO!
  }
}
```

This repository class uses your JPA EntityManager at run-time.

Comment: Spring Data is a wrapper around an ORM framework.